# Java Heap Space on JBoss and Quartz Stopped running

Tags: java, jboss, heap-memory, quartz-scheduler

I'm working with JBoss 5.1.0.GA and Quartz Sheduler.
When my JBoss occurs a Java Heap Space, my Quartz sheduler stop.
The strange thing is: my Jboss is still running after that

This is my stack

```
    2012-12-19 10:32:21,296 ERROR [STDERR] (AOPListner) Exception in thread "AOPListner" 
2012-12-19 10:32:26,531 ERROR [STDERR] (AOPListner) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2012-12-19 10:32:26,531 ERROR [STDERR] (AOPListner)     at java.util.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:416)
2012-12-19 10:32:28,125 ERROR [STDERR] (AOPListner)     at org.jboss.aop.AspectManager.getAdvisors(AspectManager.java:546)
2012-12-19 10:32:29,703 ERROR [STDERR] (AOPListner)     at org.jboss.console.plugins.AOPLister$RefreshPoller.run(AOPLister.java:891)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread) Exception in thread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" 
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronExpression.addToSet(CronExpression.java:852)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronExpression.storeExpressionVals(CronExpression.java:483)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:376)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:248)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronExpression.clone(CronExpression.java:1375)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.CronTrigger.clone(CronTrigger.java:431)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTrigger(RAMJobStore.java:1161)
2012-12-19 10:32:45,593 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread)   at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:233)
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you should understand that this is an error, not an exception. Basically once you get out of memory in Java your process becomes unstable and you cannot really be sure what will be the results of your program execution in future, even if the jboss continues to run.

I would suggest to take a memory dump (there is a parameter in JVM that allows to save memory dump once this error occurs). Then Analize it with your favourite profiler (VisualVM is free and bundled to JDK, or you can use any other) and try to find why the error occurs, and not how to keep Quartz running.

It can be application leak, or just too much objects created. In any case it should be analyzed.

Of course usually an "instant" solution for this is just increasing memory heap size for your java process, but if you say its not an option, I won't elaborate on this...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That's why these are called Error.  So it is always good to fix the memory issues and restart the servers as you might experience abnormal behaviors when it recovers from the out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to allocate more memory to your jboss server and restart it

Comment: I know that i need allocate more memory to my jboss, but my client doesnt have this possibility now and i needed that my quartz dont stopped

Comment: Is there any possibility to start jboss with minimal services?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stop and backup+drop Jboss as's or esb's automatically created tables like above;

> `JBM_USER JBM_ROLE JBM_POSTOFFICE JBM_MSG JBM_COUNTER ... etc.`

Then you should restart server.

This solved our problem.